# XAMPP - MySQL shutdown unexpectedly

Tags: mysql, xampp

After shutting down MySQL once i'm no longer able to start it again. Instead i get this error message 

`14:37:56  [mysql]   Status change detected: stopped
14:37:56  [mysql]   Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
14:37:56  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
14:37:56  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
14:37:56  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
14:37:56  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
14:37:56  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
14:37:56  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums`

Checking the log files i get the following:

`2019-07-18 14:37:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: The first innodb_system data file 'ibdata1' did not exist. A new tablespace will be created!
2019-07-18 14:37:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2019-07-18 14:37:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2019-07-18 14:37:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-07-18 14:37:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2019-07-18 14:37:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2019-07-18 14:37:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2019-07-18 14:37:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-07-18 14:37:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1' size to 10 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2019-07-18 14:37:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1' size is now 10 MB.
2019-07-18 14:37:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile101 size to 5242880 bytes
2019-07-18 14:37:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile1 size to 5242880 bytes
2019-07-18 14:37:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Renaming log file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile101 to C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile0
2019-07-18 14:37:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=45786
2019-07-18 14:37:55 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer not found: creating new
2019-07-18 14:37:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer created
2019-07-18 14:37:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2019-07-18 14:37:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables.
2019-07-18 14:37:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating tablespace and datafile system tables.
2019-07-18 14:37:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating sys_virtual system tables.
2019-07-18 14:37:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2019-07-18 14:37:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2019-07-18 14:37:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2019-07-18 14:37:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2019-07-18 14:37:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.3.16 started; log sequence number 0; transaction id 7
2019-07-18 14:37:56 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2019-07-18 14:37:56 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.`

I've tried deleting ibdbata1 file like it's reported by some people to fix the problem with no real results. I've also tried adding innodb_force_recovery = 4 to my.ini and that seemed to work for a second, port number would flash instead of straight going to the error at the bottom, but it still didn't fix the problem. At this point any help would be appreciated.